# unable to locate windows AD group for user using ldap_search in php

Tags: php, ldap

I can successfully connect and bind to ldap in windows AD using php.  However, I'm not getting the results I expect from ldap_search.  I know my test user is in Intranet_Group123 but either ldap_search isn't finding the group, or I don't know how to correctly parse the result array.  I know the distinguished name of the group:
CN=Intranet_Group123,OU=PD,OU=Intranet,OU=Apps,OU=Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com

Here's the code I'm using (based on blog here: [blog here](http://samjlevy.com/2010/09/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/)).

```
    $user = 'testuser';
    $password = 'test';
    $ldap_host = "myServer";

// Active Directory DN (I have also tried having CN=Intranet_Group123 at the beginning of the string)
$ldap_dn = "OU=PD,OU=Intranet,OU=Apps,OU=Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=com";


// Domain, for purposes of constructing $user
$ldap_usr_dom = "@mydomain.com";

// connect to active directory
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user . $ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
    var_dump($bind);  // bool•true
    // valid
    // check presence in groups
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $user . ")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    var_dump($result);  //resource(8) of type (ldap result)
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    var_dump($entries);  // array(1) {'count' → int 0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching groups container with a filter `(sAMAccountName=username)`. This is not going to produce you any meaningful results because there is no user entry in groups container, as your `var_dump($entries) shows -- // array(1) {'count' -> int 0}` just gives you a hint that no entries were found.

Instead, turn your query to a root search `(dc=mydomain,dc=com)` and search with more complex filter. You need to find a user that has particular `sAMAccountName` *and* `memberof` attribute pointing to the proper group DN. Note that `memberof` attribute accepts DN, not a group name.

The query filter then would look like this:

```
"(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=".$user.")(memberof=".$ldap_dn."))"
```

and do search over `$root_prefix` where `$root_prefix = "dc=mydomain,dc=com"` with a subtree scope.

Comment: If I change the search to $root_prefix, the search fails (it hits the "unable to search LDAP server" clause).  It appears that I need to specify at least one OU to avoid a search failure.  If I change the search to:  ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_db,"cn=*"), where $ldap_dn is the full distinguished name of the group, I get an array of arrays where one of the elements looks hopeful:      [1] => str•2 'cn'
    'member' → array(2) {
      'count' → int 1
      [0] => str•66 'CN=Test User,OU=XXX,OU=User Accounts,DC=mydomain,DC=com'  //this is the test user i'm trying to validate

Comment: ok, with a tweak to your suggestion, I got this to work.  i added the following after the ldap connection:   ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
 ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);  I then used the ldap_search as you suggested: ldap_search($ldap, $root_tree,$filter)  I also used the filter you suggested.  I now get a meaningful array, and a successful test result.

Comment: Right, I forgot about OU distinction -- you could have multiple OUs in Active Directory.